# Why am I getting a multi-part identifier could not be found?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a stored procedure and I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with it.  I need another set of eyes on it and no one here can help me.  Here is my code:

```
SELECT AP.[TermID]
  ,TE.TermName
  ,AP.[SchoolID]
  , SchoolCode, SchoolName
  ,CASE WHEN [SA_Level] = 'A' THEN 'Adult' ELSE 'Secondary' END AS StudentType
  ,DE.[DOECode]
  ,DE.[DOEName]
  ,[LabMarWage]

FROM [inters].[inters_tblApprovedProgramsTest] AP


JOIN #SchoolList SL

JOIN[inters].[inters_tblDOECode] DE
ON AP.[SchoolID] = SL.[SchoolID]
-- JOIN [inters].[inters_tblJobCode] JC 
ON AP.[CipCode] = DE.[DOECode]
LEFT JOIN [inters].[inters_tblLabMarWage] LM
ON DE.[LabMarWageID] = LM.[LabMarWageID]
JOIN [inters].[inters_tblTerm] TE
ON AP.[TermID] = TE.[TermID]
WHERE [IsActive] = 1
AND TE.TermName = @TermName
AND [SA_Level] = 'S'
AND ( @CipFilter = 0
OR ( @CipFilter = 1 AND DE.[LabMarWageID] IS NOT NULL))

ORDER BY TermName
  ,SchoolName
  ,[SA_Level]
  ,[DOECode]
  ,[CreditHours]
```

Error Message:

(11 row(s) affected)
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure JeffApprovedPrograms, Line 26
The multi-part identifier "AP.SchoolID" could not be bound.

I am not seeing the problem for some reason.  I would appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: Why is there no `JOIN` condition to your `#Schoolist` table?  You also have a couple of syntax errors, like multiple `ON` statements for a single `JOIN`...

Comment: @JNK - There is a join condition `ON AP.[SchoolID] = SL.[SchoolID]` but it is in the wrong place which causes this error message.

Comment: I am not sure why they coded it the way they did and I am trying to clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JOIN #SchoolList SL

JOIN[inters].[inters_tblDOECode] DE
ON AP.[SchoolID] = SL.[SchoolID]
-- JOIN [inters].[inters_tblJobCode] JC 
ON AP.[CipCode] = DE.[DOECode]
```

Should be

```
JOIN #SchoolList SL
    ON AP.[SchoolID] = SL.[SchoolID]    
JOIN [inters].[inters_tblDOECode] DE
    ON AP.[CipCode] = DE.[DOECode]
```

Comment: Actually it was: ON DE.[CipCode] = DE.[DOECode]....I was comparing apples to oranges :)